# Postgres C API: How can we copy a Datum?

Tags: postgresql, c

As far as I understand, `SPI_getbinval` returns a pointer into the passed row. That is, the following would be unsafe:

```c
dat = SPI_getbinval(SPI_tuptable->vals[0], SPI_tuptable->tupdesc, 1, &isnull);
SPI_finished();
if (isnull)
    PG_RETURN_NULL();
// Unsafe since SPI_finished() deallocates SPI_tuptable
return dat;
```

The SPI interface provides the utility `SPI_copytuple`.  Is the following safe?  Is there any problem with using `SPI_tuptable->tupdesc`?  Moreover, is there a more efficient way to do this directly with the returned `Datum` instead of copying the entire `HeapTuple`?

```c
// We copy the whole tuple into the outer context.  Better way to copy an individual Datum?
dat = SPI_getbinval(SPI_copytuple(SPI_tuptable->vals[0]), SPI_tuptable->tupdesc, 1, &isnull);
SPI_finished();
if (isnull)
  PG_RETURN_NULL();
return dat;
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `Datum`?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to just return `Datum` in the most generic way as there are many functions that require this.

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out the data type, then call `datumCopy` with the appropriate arguments:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * datumCopy
 *
 * Make a copy of a non-NULL datum.
 *
 * If the datatype is pass-by-reference, memory is obtained with palloc().
 *
 * If the value is a reference to an expanded object, we flatten into memory
 * obtained with palloc().  We need to copy because one of the main uses of
 * this function is to copy a datum out of a transient memory context that's
 * about to be destroyed, and the expanded object is probably in a child
 * context that will also go away.  Moreover, many callers assume that the
 * result is a single pfree-able chunk.
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
```